# Single quote in php exec command

Tags: php, exec, quotes

I have one little problem with my php exec script.
It looks like this:

```
exec('timeout 6 sshpass -p '.$pass_verify.' ssh-copy-id "root@'.ip_verify.' -p '.port_verify.'"');
```

But I want the parameter "pass_verify" was in single quotes.
I tried to ''' but it doesn't work. 
This script has to exec the Linux command:

```
sshpass -p 'pass_verify' ssh-copy-id "root@ip_verify -p port_verify"
```

Can you help me? :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use http://us.php.net/escapeshellarg to escape *all* arguments passed to exec, one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Does escaping it not work? i.e.  `\'`

```
exec('timeout 6 sshpass -p \''.$pass_verify.'\' ssh-copy-id "root@'.$ip_verify.' -p '.$port_verify.'"');
```

As Amal pointed out, you are also missing dollar signs on your other variables (unless these were supposed to be constants?)

Comment: No error, but site loads fast.. Too fast.. And there is no effect.. Like there is a problem with vars. Like no single quotes :/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the dollar sign.

```
exec('timeout 6 sshpass -p '.$pass_verify.' 
ssh-copy-id "root@'.$ip_verify.' -p '.$port_verify.'"');
--------------------^-----------------^
```

Comment: I know, I know ;D But I have problems with quotes, not vars :)

Comment: @KamilBasista: Can you post the *exact* command you're trying to `eval()`?

Comment: @KamilBasista: No, that's the PHP code. What is the Linux command you're trying to execute with eval()?

Comment: sshpass -p 'pass_verify' ssh-copy-id "root@ip_verify -p port_verify" I posted it in first post ;D